# How to fix a white background overlapped

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to fix a white background overlapped in my popup in android studio java app.

Here I don't need the white color which is above or overlapped on the transparent popup

[image]

Here I need only the dropdown not the white color overlapped above as the image

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_transparent"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eee"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_report"
            style="@style/Item.DropDown.Text"
            android:textColor="@color/white_new"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/edit"
            android:text="@string/Report"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
            style="@style/Item.DropDown.Text"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cachet_std_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white_new"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_deleted"
            android:text="@string/Delete"/>
       </LinearLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Popup transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/popup"
    android:fromDegrees="180"
    >
</rotate>
```

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
android:fillColor="@android:color/background_dark"
android:pathData="M20,2H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v18l4,-4h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Add the code how are you creating the popup .

Answer (score 1):

The white background is not generated by the popup item; it's generated by the underlying items of the `RelativeLayout` that hosts this popup.

First you can try to add a transparent color to the `LinearLayout` & remove the `android:alpha`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/eee"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

If that doesn't work we need to see the `style/Item.DropDown.Text` style file

Comment: But the above not worked. I have the white background still. Not worked

Comment: Removed Relative and used Linear layout alone with drawable background. Still the same issue   '<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/eee"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >'

Comment: I think the background is come from the   droppyBuilder = new DroppyMenuPopup.Builder(getContext(), mIvDropDown);
            // Add custom views

            DropDownView sBarItem = new DropDownView(R.layout.dialog_dropdown, mPost, mReceiver, droppyMenuItemInterface);
            sBarItem.setClickable(true);

            droppyBuilder.addMenuItem(sBarItem);
            // Set Callback handler
            droppyBuilder.setOnClick(droppyMenuItemInterface);
            droppyMenu = droppyBuilder.build();

Comment: @sejn I have no idea what `DroppyMenuPopup` is .. I couldn't also reproduce the issue of yours .. I have no white background like yours so it might be smoething that you did programmatically or in styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Dialog**. Try this.

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: I am not using dialog. I have customized the popup as I entioned aboe in my code. Are you mentioning the Dialog is any package?

Comment: I am suggesting you to use Dialog class in java or koltin which one you are using here you can use this class    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(.this);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.surebox);